# Converting DSL Query to NEST (elasticsearch)

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

My DSL query that I have in Kibana is :

```
GET elastic-search-app-log*/_search
{
  "_source": ["@timestamp", "level", "messageTemplate", "message"],  
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "_id" : "x5pcgHkBlRaz9flxW1uw"
    }
  }
}
```

Which will return the following in the CLI:

```
{
  "took" : 19,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 1,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "elastic-search-app-logs-development-2021-05",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "x5pcgHkBlRaz9flxW1uw",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "@timestamp" : "2021-05-18T11:43:25.6155311-05:00",
          "level" : "Error",
          "message" : "Something bad happened",
          "messageTemplate" : "Something bad happened"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**This is what I attempted to do, but it gives me an error when I build it:**

```
        [HttpGet("{_id}")]
        public async Task<EsSource> Get(String _id) 
        {
            var response = await _elasticClient.Search<EsSource>(s => s
                .Source(src => src.Includes(i => i
                                  .Fields(f => f.TimeStamp,
                                          f => f.Level,
                                          f => f.MessageTemplate,
                                          f => f.Message)))
                .Index("elastic-search-app-logs*")
                .Query(q => q
                    .Match(m => m.Field("_id").Query(_id))));

            return response?.Documents?.FirstOrDefault();
        }
```

My EsSource Model class:

```
public class EsSource
{
    public String TimeStamp { get; set; }
    public String Level { get; set; }
    public String MessageTemplate { get; set; }
    public String Message { get; set; }
}
```

Error in VS19 says:

`ESController.cs(39,28,47,61): error CS1061: 'ISearchResponse<EsSource>' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no accessible extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'ISearchResponse<EsSource>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

**Am I not translating the DSL query to NEST correctly?** I am extremely new to this and would love all the help I can get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `Search` method to `SearchAsync` as return type from `Search` is `ISearchResponse<EsSource>` and it doesn't contain `GetAwaiter` so you can't `await` on it.

```
[HttpGet("{_id}")]
public async Task<EsSource> Get(String _id) 
{
    var response = await _elasticClient.SearchAsync<EsSource>(s => s
        .Source(src => src.Includes(i => i
                          .Fields(f => f.TimeStamp,
                                  f => f.Level,
                                  f => f.MessageTemplate,
                                  f => f.Message)))
        .Index("elastic-search-app-logs*")
        .Query(q => q
            .Match(m => m.Field("_id").Query(_id))));

    return response?.Documents?.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That made it work, did not realize I was using `Search` and not `SearchAsync`. On another note, do you know how home when I enter the `_id` that is shown in the original post and execute it on swagger, timeStamp is displaying null but everything else is displaying? Is there something causing it to be null even though timeStamp in the CLI is actually showing a value? Let me know if I need to better clarify this

Comment: That's because you are working with `response.Documents` and your type doesn't have Id prop. You can add it to your type or you can use `response.Hits` which contains matched documents and meta data for it.

Comment: I attempted to use `response.hits` cannot implicitly convert type `System.Collections.Gneric.IReadOnlyCollection<Nest.IHit<ESPractice.Models.EsSource>>` to `ESPractice.Models.EsSource` and it recommended a cast so I did that and still gave me an error. I then tried `return response?.Hits.Select(h => h.Source)`  and tried `return?.Hits?.FirstOrDefault()` instead of the `return?.Documents?.FirstOrDefault()` and still gave me an error. Not sure why it is doing that

Comment: Think it should be `return?.Hits?.FirstOrDefault()?.Source` instead of `return?.Hits?.FirstOrDefault()`.